# Sudoku solver in python using backtracking

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, sudoku

I saw a few sudoku solvers implementations ,but I cant figure out the problem in my code. I have a function sudokusolver which becomes sudoku Board and must return solved sudoku board.

```
def sudokutest(s,i,j,z):
    # z is the number
    isiValid = np.logical_or((i+1<1),(i+1>9));
    isjValid = np.logical_or((j+1<1),(j+1>9));
    iszValid = np.logical_or((z<1),(z>9));
    if s.shape!=(9,9):
        raise(Exception("Sudokumatrix not valid"));
    if isiValid:
        raise(Exception("i not valid"));
    if isjValid:
        raise(Exception("j not valid"));
    if iszValid:
        raise(Exception("z not valid"));

    if(s[i,j]!=0):
        return False;

    for ii in range(0,9):
        if(s[ii,j]==z):
            return False;

    for jj in range(0,9):
        if(s[i,jj]==z):
            return False;

    row = int(i/3) * 3;
    col = int(j/3) * 3;
    for ii in range(0,3):
        for jj in range(0,3):
            if(s[ii+row,jj+col]==z):
                return False;

    return True;

def possibleNums(s , i ,j):
    l = [];
    ind = 0;
    for k in range(1,10):
        if sudokutest(s,i,j,k):
            l.insert(ind,k);
            ind+=1;
    return l;

def sudokusolver(S):
    zeroFound = 0;
    for i in range(0,9):
        for j in range(0,9):
            if(S[i,j]==0):
                zeroFound=1;
                break;
        if(zeroFound==1):
            break;
    if(zeroFound==0):
          return S;

    x = possibleNums(S,i,j);
    for k in range(len(x)):
        S[i,j]=x[k];
        sudokusolver(S);
    S[i,j] = 0;
    sudokusolver(S);
    return S;
```

sudokutest and possibleNums are correct , only sudokusolver give a RecursionError

Answer (score 1):

Along with backtracking recursive search, you could also improve your algorithm by using some heuristics such as least remaining value heuristic and constraint propagation techniques such as forward checking and arc-consistency to reduce the domain of the variables to be assigned, by ensuring consistency.

The following animation shows an example Sudoku puzzle solution with all the heuristics and constraint propagation, thereby making the recursive BT search much faster.

#### Input

[image]

### Last few steps of the Sudoku solver with AC-3 / BT with RMV heuristic / forward checking (it takes total 369 steps for the BT search to find a solution and it returns pretty fast, total time to find the solution ~ 2 secs)

[image]

### Here is part of the backtracking tree:

[image]

For details you may want to refer to https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/solving-sudoku-as-a-constraint-satisfaction-problem-using-constraint-propagation-with-arc-consistency-checking-and-then-backtracking-with-minimum-remaning-value-heuristic-and-forward-checking/?frame-nonce=9d28c0c035

Answer (score 0):

In the last three lines:

```
S[i,j] = 0;
sudokusolver(S);
return S;
```

you always reset the changes, so S will never be filled. The recursion at the end should not be needed.

Comment: I tried with 
x = possibleNums(S,i,j);
    for k in range(len(x)):
        S[i,j]=x[k];
        return sudokusolver(S);
    S[i,j] = 0;
    
    return S;

but for hard sudokus it stops

Comment: I think this wont help

Comment: @SHristoskov, did you try it or do you just assume that it won't work?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Maybe for easy sudoku will be working but not for the hard one