# How do I iterate through a list recursively? [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been writing this program to solve sudoku problems. My brute forcing program so far looks for the first appearance of a '.' character, then brute forces possible combinations on that index.

I've been trying to write my code so that it chooses indices to brute force based on the number of possible solutions (i.e. the indices with the fewest possible solutions will be brute forced first).

Here is my (commented) code so far:

```
def bruteForce(pzl, pos):
  if isInvalid(pzl, pos): return '' #if the puzzle is invalid (specifically the last placed symbol), return ''
  if isSolved(pzl): return pzl      #if the puzzle is solved, return the puzzle
  for possibleChoice in comboFinder(pzl, pos):   #for each possible choice in the combo finder
    if indexList:  # if there are any '.' indices left
      pos1 = indexList[0]  #deal with the position with the lowest number of possible symbols
      findPoz(pzl) #updates pozList
      bF = bruteForce(possibleChoice, pos1)  #bruteforce the possible puzzle
      indexList.pop(0) #delete the first element after finishing recursion
      if bF: return bF
  return ''
```

comboFinder returns a set of possible combinations given a puzzle (pzl) and an index of a '.' character to replace with a symbol (pos).

indexList is a list of indices where '.' appears, sorted by number of possible symbols, from low to high (i.e. an index where there's only one possible symbol would be at the front of the list). I've appended a 0 at the end of the list to ensure that pos1 is never out of range. indexList is generated at the start of every solving and is updated with pozList, but I've found that this causes a maximum recursion depth error.

I am aware that my issue has to do with the placement (or just the existence) of the .pop(0), but I can't think of any other way to move through the list the way I need to.

Comment: Look into **recursive backtracking** instead.

Comment: @PM77-1 Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133357/sudoku-solver-in-python-using-backtracking

Comment: I'm not sure we can usefully help you here, since we can't tell what `comboFinder` does, or what `indexList` contains (or how it's updated).

Comment: @Blckknght Edited for clarity.